# Collision between RestTemplate with basic authentication and exchange method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, basic-authentication, resttemplate

I am using Spring 4.3 and SpringBoot 1.5 to create a component that has to call an external REST service. This external service requests HTTP Basic Authentication.

I found that SpringBoot provides a very useful builder to set up `RestTemplate` properties, such as basic authentication, [`RestTemplateBuilder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/client/RestTemplateBuilder.html).

To call the external REST service I have to use the method `RestTemplate.exchange`, because of the `List<T>` return type.

```
new RestTemplateBuilder().basicAuthorization(username, password)
                         .build()
                         .exchange("/some/path/with/variables",
                                   HttpMethod.GET,
                                   new HttpEntity<>(new HttpHeaders()),
                                   new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Integer>>() {},
                                   some, params)
```

The problem here is that the signature of the `exchange` method requests an object of type `HttpEntity`, that is basically a container of `HttpHeaders`.

**The question is**, will the `HttpEntity` object, passed as input parameter to the `exchange` method, subscribe the Basic Auth header set using the `RestTemplateBuilder.basicAuthorization` method?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should elaborate your question. It is essentially is not properly grammatically formed.

Comment: Question modified. Is it better now?

Comment: It is better, yes. But now my commentary: have you tried it?

Comment: Nope. I am in an analysis phase. I am asking if someone has already tried it and can give me a help. Seems legit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done some experiments during the past couple of days. The instance of `HttpEntity` passed to the `exchange` method **does not** subscribe the information relative to the Basic Authentication set by the `RestTemplateBuilder`. The two sets of headers are merged into one.

Nice shot, Spring ;)